# Oracle query to return values from column 1 for certain values in column 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a statement that gets data from 4 tables. The result of this select statement will provide me with the information i need from a start. I then have a second select statement where i want to filter these results on.

the statement looks like this

```
WITH temp
     AS (SELECT "username",
                Max("session_start_time") AS "START_TIME",
                "product_name"
         FROM   (SELECT "PPM"."ppm_logon_sessions"."session_start_time" AS
                        "SESSION_START_TIME",
                        "PPM"."ppm_logon_sessions"."username"           AS
                        "USERNAME"
                        ,
                        "PPM"."ppm_logon_sessions"."user_id"
                        AS "USER_ID",
                        "Knta User Products"."product_id"               AS
                        "PRODUCT_ID",
                        "Knta User Products"."user_id"                  AS
                        "USER_ID_2",
                        "Knta User Products"."user_product_id"          AS
                        "USER_PRODUCT_ID",
                        "Knta License Usage V"."product_name"           AS
                        "PRODUCT_NAME"
                 FROM   "PPM"."ppm_logon_sessions"
                        left join "PPM"."knta_user_products"
                                  "Knta User Products"
                               ON "PPM"."ppm_logon_sessions"."user_id" =
                                  "Knta User Products"."user_id"
                        left join "PPM"."knta_license_usage_v"
                                  "Knta License Usage V"
                               ON "Knta User Products"."product_id" =
                                  "Knta License Usage V"."product_id")
         GROUP  BY "username", "product_name")
SELECT "username", "product_name"
FROM   temp
WHERE  "start_time" > Trunc(Cast(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)
                            + Numtodsinterval(-30, 'day'), 'day')
       AND "product_name" IS NOT NULL
```

Now this will return a set of results that looks like this:

[image: output of query]

what i would like to do if return only the usernames where they exists in only certain products, for example if i wanted to filter out only users that have "Configuration" and "User Administration" product_names it should give me only those users, not users that have "Configuration" and "User Administration" and "Program Management"

Comment: So, if one user has "Configuration" and "User Administration" and also has "Project Management", should it be selected?

Comment: No. only if you select it in the select statement other wise no, the user must exist in only what you select. the answer provided below is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using **LEAD** and **LAG** analytical functions.

Demo:

In the below sample data, it will only return the `username` which has product *only* in `'Configuration', 'User Administration'` and filter if others:

```
with t AS
( 
  select 'mat_m' username, 'Configuration' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'mat_m' username, 'Program Management' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'mat_m' username, 'Project Management' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'nel_d' username, 'User Administration' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'nel_d' username, 'Program Management' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'nel_d' username, 'Portfolio Management' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'puth_a' username, 'Configuration' product_name from dual
  union all
  select 'puth_a' username, 'User Administration' product_name from dual
 )
 SELECT username, product_name
 FROM(
    SELECT username, 
           product_name,
           lead(product_name) over(partition by username order by product_name) lead,
           lag(product_name) over(partition by username order by product_name) lag
    FROM t
    )
WHERE product_name IN ('Configuration', 'User Administration')
AND 
(
    lag IN ('Configuration', 'User Administration')
  OR
    lead IN ('Configuration', 'User Administration')
);
```

Output:

```
USERNAME PRODUCT_NAME        
-------- --------------------
puth_a   Configuration       
puth_a   User Administration
```